# Implementing map on a tree using fold

Tags: scala, haskell

I am trying to implement a map using fold. I could do so in Haskell

```
 data Tree a = EmptyTree | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving (Show)


 foldTree :: Tree a -> b -> (b -> a -> b -> b) ->  b   
 foldTree EmptyTree d _ = d
 foldTree (Node a l r) d f =  f (foldTree l d f)  a  (foldTree r d f)


 mapTree :: Tree a -> ( a -> b) -> Tree b
 mapTree tree f = foldTree tree EmptyTree (\l n r -> Node (f n)  l  r)
```

However when I tried to port it to Scala, I am a bit stuck

```
sealed trait Tree[+A]
case object EmptyTree extends Tree[Nothing]
case class Node[A](value: A , left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]


def fold[A, B](t:Tree[A] , z:B)(f:(B,A,B) => B) : B = t match {
    case EmptyTree => z 
    case Node(x,l,r) => f ( fold( l , z )(f) , x , fold( r , z )(f) )   
  }

  def map(tree:Tree[Int])(f:Int=>Int) : Tree[Int] = fold(tree , EmptyTree)((l,x,r) => Node(f(x),l,r))
```

The compiler complains that it is expecting an EmptyTree in function I pass to fold.

```
fold(tree , EmptyTree)((l,x,r) => Node(f(x),l,r))
```

The return type for the Map is Tree so I would have expected this to work. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to write your last line as

```
def map(tree:Tree[Int])(f:Int=>Int) : Tree[Int] = fold(tree , EmptyTree:Tree[Int])((l,x,r) => Node(f(x),l,r))
```

Scala's type inference is very limited compared to haskell, in this case it tries to infere type of `fold` from it's arguments left to right, and incorectly decides that result type of fold should be `EmptyTree` and not the `Tree[Int]`. Usually adding auxilary constructor to the companion object of the parent type helps in this situation a bit, for instance in the Option object there's a constructor

```
def empty[A]: Option[A]
```

which returns the parent type.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @vitalii's solution, make the type parameters to `fold` explicit:

```
def map(tree: Tree[Int])(f: Int=>Int): Tree[Int] =
  fold[Int, Tree[Int]](tree, EmptyTree)((l, x, r) => Node[Int](f(x), l, r))
  //   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```